# Would Move Semantic in C++ 11 be executed if there is no rvalue parameter with function signature?

Tags: c++, c++11, move, move-semantics

To make program run more efficiently, move semantic is introduced since C++ 11, for example:

```
void fun(const string& str); //1st
void fun(string&& str); //2nd since c++ 11
```

If I use it like `fun("tmpStr");`, the 2nd function signatured with rvalue would be used,and it is more efficient than the 1st function.

But the problem is that if I need ONLY 1 function signature to handle paramters with both lvalue and rvalue, what shoud I do?

1. if the 1st one is kept, it is not efficient with rvalue;
2. if the 2nd one is kept, it is efficient with rvalue, but I have to `fun(std::move(lvalue))` to make it possible with lvalue, which I think the added codes `std::move` looks like redundant---moreover, this makes the status of lvalue undefined after this function.

With the thought above, I wonder if  Move Semantic in C++ 11 would be executed if there is no rvalue parameter with function signature like the 1st one, even just in release(optimized) mode?
if the answer is not , then what is the reason behind it?

Comment: The rvalue reference alone does not make a function immediately "more efficient". This is the wrong sort of thinking. If those functions do the same thing, you can stick to the const lvalue ref.

Comment: `std::move` is not redundant because it makes overload resolution work and lvalue is kept in valid state

Comment: A string literal like "tmpStr" is a `const char*`.

Comment: Is there a special reason you are using "2ed" instead of "2nd"?  Because the word is "second".

Comment: @L.F.,sorry for that, I've fixed it.

Comment: @StoryTeller, Indeed, I am sticking to the const lvalue ref at present. Just because I think it kind of waste of not using move semantic  dealing with temporary variable, and also I don't want to write more than one function signatures, I asked the question.

Comment: @VTT, I know it is not redundant actually, and I just think it "looks" like redundant as it need programmer to write more code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move semantics is irrelevant in this case because you don't want to modify the argument.

`"tmpStr"` is not a `std::string`, it is a `const char*`.  Since you are taking a non-(const lvalue) reference to `std::string`, the compiler has to create a `std::string` somewhere.  Allocation overhead is already incurred.  Then, which reference you use really doesn't matter if you don't modify the temporary string.  The best way to write the function is:

```
void fun(std::string_view sv)
```

This automatically handles string literals and `std::string`s, etc., and incurs zero allocation overhead.  This is more efficient than moving.  No move semantics involved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I would use std::string_view afterwards.

Comment: @DongRobbin If you find this answer useful, you can accept it by clicking the tick on the left, underneath the vote buttons, so that the question is marked solved.